# Angular-CLI proxy to path

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am trying to configure my local angular cli instance to proxy my requests to a specific path. Examples on the internet show only proxying to a domain.
The documentation on proxying didn't help me much either.
What I am trying is:

```
{
   "/portal/*": {
     "target": "http://my.host/portal/",
     "secure": false,
     "logLevel": "debug",
     "changeOrigin": true
   }
}
```

I want all requests made to `/portal/` to go to `http://my.host/portal/` like `portal/api/v1/customer/13` to `my.host/portal/api/v1/customer/13`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using proxy, set `target` to your domain ONLY.
Your angular-cli makes request to `my.host/portal/portal/api/v1/customer/13`

Change your json to following (delete context root from target domain)

```
{
   "/portal/*": {
     "target": "http://my.host",
     "secure": false,
     "logLevel": "debug",
     "changeOrigin": true
   }
}
```